Show that $\Lambda_\varphi(x_n)\to \Lambda_\varphi(x)$ for an nsf weight $\varphi$ on a von Neumann algebra
Let $\varphi$ be an nsf weight on a von Neumann algebra $M$. Fix a square-integrable element $x\in \mathscr{N}_\varphi$. Put
$$x_n := \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-nt^2) \sigma_t^\varphi(x) dt$$
with $\{\sigma_t^\varphi\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ the modular group associated to $\varphi$.
It can be shown that
$$x_n \in \mathscr{N}_\varphi\cap \mathscr{N}_\varphi^*.$$
I am trying to prove that with $\Lambda_\varphi: \mathscr{N}_\varphi\to \mathcal{H}_\varphi = L^2(M, \varphi)$ the GNS-map, we have that
$$\|\Lambda_\varphi(x)-\Lambda_\varphi(x_n)\|\to 0.$$
(This is a claim from the book "Modular theory in operator algebras" by Stratila, see p19).
I tried to calculate
$$\|\Lambda_\varphi(x)-\Lambda_\varphi(x_n)\|^2 = \varphi((x-x_n)^*(x-x_n))$$
but then I got stuck. How can I proceed/prove this claim?
Thanks in advance for your help!

For $x\in \mathcal N_\phi$ you have $\Lambda_\phi(\sigma_t^\phi(x)) = \Delta^{it} \Lambda_\phi(x)$ (see equation (9) on page 27 in the book of Stratila). Since $\Lambda_\phi \colon \mathcal N_\phi \to \mathcal H_\phi$ is SOT-weakly-continuous (equation (13) page 28) one therefore has $\Lambda_\phi(x_n) = (n/\pi)^{1/2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-nt^2} \Delta^{it} \Lambda_\phi(x) \mathrm dt$ where the integral is defined a priori with respect to the weak topology on $\mathcal H_\phi$, but since $t\mapsto \Delta^{it} \Lambda_\phi(x)$ is norm-continuous, this is the same as the integral defined with respect to the norm topology.  Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray}
\| \Lambda_\phi(x) - \Lambda_\phi(x_n) \| &=& \sqrt{\tfrac{n}{\pi}} \left\| \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-n t^2} (\Lambda_\phi(x) - \Delta^{it} \Lambda_\phi(x)) \mathrm dt \right\| \\
&\leq& \sqrt{\tfrac{n}{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-n t^2} \| \Lambda_\phi(x) - \Delta^{it} \Lambda_\phi(x)\| \mathrm dt.
\end{eqnarray}
This tends to zero as $n\to \infty$, in fact, any continuous and bounded function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies $\sqrt{\tfrac{n}{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-n t^2} f(t) \mathrm dt \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f(0)$. (This is an elementary exercise using dominated convergence after splitting the integral into two parts for $|t|\leq \epsilon$ and $|t|\geq \epsilon$).

Thanks! (For the elementary exercise you mention: I don't see the need to split the integral in two parts though: $\sqrt{n/\pi} \int e^{-nt^2} f(t)dt = \sqrt{1/\pi} \int e^{-t^2}f(t/\sqrt{n}) dt\to \sqrt{1/\pi} \int e^{-t^2} f(0) dt = f(0)$ by dominated convergence.)

Oh yeah, that's easier than what I had in mind!
